# Crystal Reports 11 Hide field until formula is run

Tags: crystal-reports-xi, suppress

I have a report in Crystal Reports 11 that has 2 images at the top of the page in the header.  I have a formula that runs down in the footer.  I would like to hide/show these images based on the value of the formula but when the report loads, the images load before the formula runs so they don't display properly.  Is there a way to delay load of something in the header until something has been run at the end?  Basically, load an image at the end of the report running?

The scenario is a dual receipt/invoice statement.  The formula balance owed resides in Footer Group Footer 3H.  The text boxes are in Group Header 3a.  At the time the report is run, @BalanceOwed shows a balance but when the report is fully run, @BalanceOwed is 0.  So in this case, the text box Receipt should show vs. the text box Invoice and then it works in the opposite if @BalanceOwed is > 0.

I know how to suppress something based on values but not based on values that don't exist at the time the report builds the element to hide/display.

Thanks.

Jayson

Answer (score 0):

Use the EvaluateAfter() function in the image selection formula. Give EvaluateAfter() the name of the formula in the footer that needs to run first.

You'll put the EvaluateAfter() in the conditional suppression formula of the field/image, at the top of the formula before any other logic.

EvaluateAfter() tells the crystal not to run the formula until after the specified formula has finished running.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Question as I have never used this before.  To see what happens, I created a formula that says EvaluateAfter({BalanceDue}) and placed that in the header where the text box I want to hide is.  I also placed BalanceDue there as well just to see what is shown.  I ran the report and the report comes up with a balance due on the report of 409.00.  That is in the Balance Due box on the invoice.  In the header, BalanceDue shows 409.00 and EvaluateAfter({BalanceDue}) shows 0.  When I run this with any potential invoice/receipt, the EvaluateAfter call always show 0.

Comment: I believe the format should actually be `EvaluateAfter({@BalanceDue})`

Comment: You are correct on the format and that is my format. I removed the @ symbols as I could not post the response with them in it.

Comment: Oh, now that I read your previous comment, I may have more insight. For the text box you want to suppress, are you using conditional suppression? You'll want to add the EvaluateAfter({@BalanceDue}) into the suppression formula at the top.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am doing.  I open the X+2 for suppress on that element and add that EvaluateAfter statement.  The problem is that when I do that, the value of that is 0 always even though when that is run later in the footer, it is not.

Comment: What's the rest of your conditional suppression formula?

Comment: Simple, evaluateafter({@balancedue}) <>0

Comment: You dont need the`<>0` part after the EvaluateAfter(@balancedue). Sounds like you're missing the rest of your conditional suppression formula. The part where you check the value of balance owed. Remember to write it the opposite of when that object should appear. If you have more questions about how to create the correct conditional suppression formula, first search on SO (or the search engine of your choice), and then post another question, as it's off-topic for this question.